# How can I decode this json with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

I want to print just value for key `"User_number"`

```
 [
   {
     "User_fullname": null,
     "User_sheba": null,
     "User_modifiedAT": "2019-01-31T18:37:02.716Z",
     "_id": "5c53404e91fc822c80e75d23",
     "User_number": "9385969339",
     "User_code": "45VPMND"
   }
 ]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you share some code how are you using Alamofire? and it's a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this is some JSON in `Data` format

```
let data = Data("""
[ { "User_fullname": null, "User_sheba": null, "User_modifiedAT": "2019-01-31T18:37:02.716Z", "_id": "5c53404e91fc822c80e75d23", "User_number": "9385969339", "User_code": "45VPMND" } ]
""".utf8)
```

One way is using `SwiftyJSON` library, but, this is something what I don't suggest since you can use `Codable`.

---

So, first you need custom struct conforming to `Decodable` (note that these `CodingKeys` are here to change key of object inside json to name of property of your struct)

```
struct User: Decodable {

    let fullname, sheba: String? // these properties can be `nil`
    let modifiedAt, id, number, code: String // note that all your properties are actually `String` or `String?`

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fullname = "User_fullname"
        case sheba = "User_sheba"
        case modifiedAt = "User_modifiedAT"
        case id = "_id"
        case number = "User_number"
        case code = "User_code"
    }
}
```

then decode your json using `JSONDecoder`

```
do {
    let users = try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)
} catch { print(error) }
```

---

So, now you have `Data` decoded as array of your custom model. So if you want to, you can just get certain `User` and its `number` property

```
let user = users[0]
let number = user.number
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code takes takes in `Data` and saves "User_number" as an `Int`

```
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data!, options: []) as! NSDictionary {
    let User_number= json["User_number"] as! Int
}
```

Comment: Oh, you really shouldn’t recommend `JSONSerialization` in cases like this. Anyway, this is Swift, use native type `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`